# What is the best way to pass session data from a Client component to a server component in NEXT.js 13>?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, next-auth

I am developing a web app where I need to pass `session?.user?.email` from `useSession()` in `next-auth/react` to a sever side component where it carries out a fetch request to `/api/users/email/` to find out if a user exists with that particular email address.

After reading the documentation, I realised that you are not supposed to use server components inside `'use client'` components where I have my `useSession()`

What is the best way to structure this?

Comment: You did get the answer from your previous question https://github.com/travco/postcss-extend

Comment: No, your suggestions did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `getServerSession` method to get it on server component directly:

```js
export default async function ServerComponent() {
const session = getServerSession(authOptions) // auth options you defined somewhere to consume with handler

return <> {session?.user.email} </>
}
```

I suppose using useSession on client makes additional requests as stated here [link](https://next-auth.js.org/getting-started/client):
*Due to the way Next.js handles getServerSideProps and getInitialProps, every protected page load has to make a server-side request to check if the session is valid and then generate the requested page (SSR). This increases server load, and **if you are good with making the requests from the client, there is an alternative. You can use useSession** in a way that makes sure you always have a valid session. If after the initial loading state there was no session found, you can define the appropriate action to respond.*

So maybe reconsider getting it on server and then passing to client when needed

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on [@ColdDarkness](https://stackoverflow.com/users/20480318/colddarkness)'s response, this is what worked for me:

A file simply to export `SessionProvider` from a client component:

```
"use client";

export { SessionProvider as Provider } from 'next-auth/react';
```

An asynchronous auth provider component:

```
import { Provider } from "./SessionProvider";
import { getServerSession } from "next-auth";
import { authOptions } from "@/lib/auth";

type Props = {
    children?: React.ReactNode;
}

const AuthProvider = async ({ children }: Props) => {

    const session = await getServerSession(authOptions);

    return <Provider session={session}>
        {children}
    </Provider>;
}


export default AuthProvider;
```

Then wrapped around my layout:

```
export default function Layout({
    children,
}: {
    children: React.ReactNode
}) {

    return (
        <body>
            <AuthProvider>
                {children}
            </AuthProvider>
        </body>
    )
}
```